# How to fix 'Call to undefined function do_settings()' error?

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, fatal-error

I am writing my first plugin and to access/save options I follow [codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages) I basically copied the example from 'See It All Together' in a separate file `mhomepage_admin_menu.php`

The main code of the plugin goes like

```
if ( is_admin() ){ // admin actions
    add_action('admin_menu', 'add_plugin_admin_page' );
    add_action('admin_init', 'register_mhomepage_settings' );

} else {
  // non-admin enqueues, actions, and filters
}

function register_mhomepage_settings() { // whitelist options
  register_setting( 'mhomepage_option_group', 'left_right_margin_option' );
  register_setting( 'mhomepage_option_group', 'top_margin_option' );
  register_setting( 'mhomepage_option_group', 'include_comments_option' );
}  

function add_plugin_admin_page($plugin_name) {
    add_menu_page( 'mHomePage', 'mHomePage', 'manage_options', 'mhomepage/mhomepage_admin_menu.php', '', '', 6 );

}
```

and the beginning of `mhomepage_admin_menu.php` looks like

```
<div class="wrap">
<h2>Your Plugin Name</h2>

<form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php settings_fields( 'mhomepage_option_group' ); ?>
    <?php do_settings( 'mhomepage_option_group' ); ?>
    <table class="form-table">
```

I have to questions

- Q1: how to fix the error?
- Q2: what is the correct file name in `<form method="post" action="options.php">`? Is that `mhomepage_admin_menu.php`?

Comment: You have not provided a callback function for your page in the `add_menu_page` call, it should reference a function to execute when that page is requested. You've registered a slug for the page(4th param), but no function to call(5th param - it should refer to a function and not a file - even though you've included neither in the above code).

Comment: Additionally, that `is_admin` conditional at the top of your code is not required, those actions only run on the admin end, so the conditional is unnecessary.

Comment: A quote from http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page : `$menu_slug
    (string) (required) The slug name to refer to this menu by (should be unique for this menu). If the function parameter is omitted, the menu_slug should be the PHP file that handles the display of the menu page content` This part is working fine, not sure what you are pointing out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1: [H]ow to fix the error?

Stop calling the `do_settings()` function in this line. It is not a WordPress function and it is apparently not a function that you have defined. Perhaps you meant to use one of [these functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API#Function_Reference).

```
<?php do_settings( 'mhomepage_option_group' ); ?>
```

> Q2: [W]hat is the correct file name in `<form method="post" action="options.php">`?

```
options.php
```

Comment: Q2: if I used your code I get `The requested URL /wp-admin/mhomepage/mhomepage_admin_menu.php was not found on this server.` The php file is in the plugin directory.

Comment: Q2: If I use simply `options.php` I can save :-) I will accept your answer if you update it ...

Answer (score 0):

You need use the function inside an admin hook in order for the settings functions to exists in the environnement. Eg.: `add_action('admin_menu', 'your_function_name');`

Answer (score -4):

Check WP Error Fix plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-bug-tracker/. It can fix this type of error automatically. I'm using it and it works great.

Comment: A bug-tracking plugin isn't the solution to **fix** something, it just do the **detection**.